# Hibernate self join - prevent removing on cascade from child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have exact this table (omitted fields does not matter):

```
ID  |   NAME   | PARENT_ID
```

After adding two rows it looks exact:

```
ID  |   NAME   | PARENT_ID
1      "ONE"       null
2      "TWO"         1
```

And now, when I delete second row, the first one is also removed. I would like to cascade only from parent to child, so when I remove a row with ID 2 it should delete only this one row. In case I remove row with ID 1 it should remove both rows. Could someone help me with achieving that?

This is how my Entity looks:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@DynamicUpdate
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "name")
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners({AuditingEntityListener.class})
class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Product> products;

    @Setter
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    @Column(unique = true, length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    @Setter
    @Accessors(chain = true)
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory")
    private Set<Category> subCategories = new HashSet<>();

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    @Getter
    private Instant creationDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Getter
    @Version
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    Category(String name, Category parentCategory){
        this.name = name;
        this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I would like to cascade only from parent to child*: then why did you specify `@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})` on parentCategory. That **precisely** does what you **don't** want to do. And why ddn't you specify an cascade on the OneToMany, since that's what you want?

Comment: Right, my bad. Thank you :)